# Significant lag time when Jenkins pipeline jobs connect to SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins-pipeline

We are currently using the SCM Step Pipeline plugin to connect to svn Global Library and svn source code.

- SCM Step Pipeline plugin version: 2.4
- SVN version: 1.9.4

We are noticing significant lag time when pipeline jobs connect to svn. For example, the code below takes anywhere from 2 mins to up to 10 mins:

```
Started by user Manoj,kumar
Loading library vent-global-library@trunk
Opening connection to http://plsvnvc001/securesvn/SecurityServices/ventglobal-library/
Updating http://plsvnvc001/securesvn/SecurityServices/thrivent-globallibrary/trunk@16081 at revision 16081
Using sole credentials xsvnBatch/****** (svn access) in realm ‘<http://plsvnvc001:80> secure Subversion repository’
```

At revision 16081
Have you experienced an issue similar to this? Any suggestions on how to fix?

Regards,
Manojkumar

Comment: How long does it take you to perform a checkout/update normally?  Is it comparable to the time Jenkins takes?

Comment: Its taking 2 to 10 min